# Array converted into a string is used to be converted into a number but does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a calculator with HTML, CSS and and pure JavaScript. 
I tried to do it just with little information, but I cannot understand what is happening now. Since a person type many digits (i.e 456) to create a number and then click on the operator, I decided to create an array(arrayInput) that will hold the numbers 4,5,6 and even the character "." So for instance 4.56 in the array appears as 4,.,5,6 so I removed the characters and then the whitespaces. Finally since it is now a string "4.56" I used Number() function to convert it to number. I also used parseInt, parseFloat, but it only displays the first time and when an operator is selected, then it does not calculate the total, but remains with the total zero. I will appreciate your support.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <style type='text/css'>
    .row{
    height: 2em;
    width: 25%;
    border: 0.05em solid black;
    float:left;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
}
#screen{
    height: 4em;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0.03em solid black;
    float:left;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-style: sans-serif;
    text-align:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}


  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>

var total=0;  //which will replace the number1 in parameters
var numberArray=[];
var operator="plus";  //by default i give it an addition
var number=0;
//get digits from buttons to create the number you want to use

var performOperator=function (tot,num,ope){
        if(ope==="plus")
            {
            tot+=num;
            num=0;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = tot;  //display a number of total HOPEFULLY
            }
        else if(ope==="-")
            {
            tot-=num;
            num=0;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = tot;  //display a number of total HOPEFULLY
            }

        else if(ope==="multiply")
            {
            tot*=num;
            num=0;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = tot;  //display a number of total HOPEFULLY
            }
        else if(ope==="/")
            {
            tot/=num;
            num=0;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = tot;  //display a number of total HOPEFULLY
            }
        else if(ope==="equal")
            {
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = tot;  //display a number of last total HOPEFULLY
            num=0;
            }
        else if(ope==="clear")
            {
            tot=0;
            num=0;
            document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = tot;  //display a number of total HOPEFULLY
            }
    }


function getDigit(elemId){


    var digitEntry=document.getElementById(elemId).value; //digit value goes to "val"
    numberArray.push(digitEntry); //each val should go to push into an array
    var numberWithSpace=numberArray.join(' '); //convert the array into a string block with spaces
    var numberNoSpace=numberWithSpace.replace(/\s/g, '');  //string number with no space
    number=Number(numberNoSpace);// it should be converter into a number here but does not look like..
    document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = number;  //probably displays array of Number as STRING 

}

function highlightSign(elemId){

    var sign=document.getElementById(elemId).value; //digit value goes to "sign""
    operator=sign;
    performOperator(total,number,operator); //Call the performOperator function and creates new total and new number 0
    numberArray=[]; //once the number is created as real number then the array used to built it clears
}



</script>


</head>
<body>
  <body>

    <p id="screen"></p>

    <button id="nC" class="row" value=""></button>
    <button id="pmSign" class="row" value=""></button>
    <button id="nPercentage" class="row" value=""></button>
    <button id="divide" class="row" value="/" onclick="highlightSign(this.id)">/</button>
    <button id="n7" class="row" value=7 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">7</button>
    <button id="n8" class="row" value=8 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">8</button>
    <button id="n9" class="row" value=9 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">9</button>
    <button id="opX" class="row" value="multiply" onclick="highlightSign(this.id)">x</button>
    <button id="n4" class="row" value=4 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">4</button>
    <button id="n5" class="row" value=5 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">5</button>
    <button id="n6" class="row" value=6 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">6</button>
    <button id="minus" class="row" value="-" onclick="highlightSign(this.id)">-</button>
    <button id="n1" class="row" value=1 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">1</button>
    <button id="n2" class="row" value=2 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">2</button>
    <button id="n3" class="row" value=3 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">3</button>
    <button id="plus" class="row" value="plus" onclick="highlightSign(this.id)">+</button>
    <button id="n0" class="row" value=0 onclick="getDigit(this.id)">0</button>
    <button id="clear" class="row" value="clear" onclick="highlightSign(this.id)">clear</button>
    <button id="decPoint" class="row" value="." onclick="getDigit(this.id)">.</button>
    <button id="equal" class="row" value="equal" onclick="highlightSign(this.id)">=</button>
</body>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: can you give a link to your jsfiddle?

Comment: I would keep converting the really big string of numbers to a really big string of bits ( 1s and 0s) and then do the math in bit chunks.   I would never do more than a 32 bit or 64 bit chunk at a time.  This will let you have an infinite long number effectively.  Do not forget to read the sign plus minus.  This will eliminate the parse in java script which may be implicitly type converted for integers or converted to floats without your knowledge.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I did get the answer. I am just still new to stackoverflow. Apologies for delay updating it. Below is the answer. I did make changes to my calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your total work here. But you need to change the logic of your calculator. There's a lot to change there

http://jsfiddle.net/g6gj1kr6/9/

Don't pass your total as parameter just make it global, then you can rewrite it.

```
var tot=0;
```

Anyway, there is a lot of work to do for your calculator